# Java Rest 404 el recurso requerido no esta disponible

Tags: java

Hola amigos necesito ayuda estoy tratando de hacer una rest api pero no me sale en java, se que es largo todo esto pero necesito de una ayuda ya que es para un Proyecto de Universidad.Gracias
este es mi codigo:
bean:

```js
package bean;

public class Album {
 
 private String idalbum;
 private String nombrealbum;
 private String fotoalbum;
 private String nombreartista;
 
 public Album(){
  
 }
 
 
 public Album(String idalbum, String nombrealbum, String fotoalbum, String nombreartista) {
  super();
  this.idalbum = idalbum;
  this.nombrealbum = nombrealbum;
  this.fotoalbum = fotoalbum;
  this.nombreartista = nombreartista;
 }


 public String getIdalbum() {
  return idalbum;
 }
 public void setIdalbum(String idalbum) {
  this.idalbum = idalbum;
 }
 public String getNombrealbum() {
  return nombrealbum;
 }
 public void setNombrealbum(String nombrealbum) {
  this.nombrealbum = nombrealbum;
 }
 public String getFotoalbum() {
  return fotoalbum;
 }
 public void setFotoalbum(String fotoalbum) {
  this.fotoalbum = fotoalbum;
 }
 public String getNombreartista() {
  return nombreartista;
 }
 public void setNombreartista(String nombreartista) {
  this.nombreartista = nombreartista;
 }
 
 

}
```

DAO:

```js
package dao;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import edu.util.MySQLConexion;
import bean.Album;


public class AlbumDAO {
 
 private MySQLConexion sql;
 public AlbumDAO(){
  this.sql = new MySQLConexion();
 }
 public List<Album> listadoAlbum(){
 List<Album> lista= new ArrayList<Album>();
 Connection cn = sql.getConnection();
 
 try{
  
  CallableStatement cs = cn.prepareCall("{call sp_album()}");
  ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
  while(rs.next()){
   
   Album album = new Album();
   album.setIdalbum(rs.getString("idalbum"));
   album.setNombrealbum(rs.getString("nombrealbum"));
   album.setFotoalbum(rs.getString("fotoalbum"));
   album.setNombreartista(rs.getString("nombreartista"));
   lista.add(album);
  }
  rs.close();
  cs.close();
  cn.close();

  }catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
  }
    System.out.println(lista);
 return lista;
 
 }

}
```

Este es mi conexion

```js
package util;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MySQLConexion {
 
 public Connection getConnection() {
  Connection cn = null;
  try {
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
   cn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ProyectoMusica", "root", "mysql");
   
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
  }
  return cn;
 }

}
```

Por ultimo este es mi servicio Rest

```js
package rest;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


import bean.Album;
import dao.AlbumDAO;

@Path("servicioAlbum")
public class ServicioAlbum {
 @Path("listarAlbum")
 @GET
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public List<Album> listarAlbum(){
  AlbumDAO albumdoDao = new AlbumDAO();
  return albumdoDao.listadoAlbum();
 }

}
```

Y esta es mi configuracion xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ServidorProyecto</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>Jersey Servicio REST Basico</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
 <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
 <param-value>rest</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Jersey Servicio REST Basico</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
  
</web-app>
```

Y por ultimos estos son mis apis
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ejecutar me sale esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberías sacar trazas de error en los bloques try-catch, ahora mismo no lo estás haciendo.

Comment: lee [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), saca un ejemplo minimo y verificable, tanto codigo no ayuda.